# How to prevent jumping the text when scroll is display?

Tags: html, css

I display the scrollbar when I hover the div.

The problem is "jump" every time the scrollbar is display. it moving the left side.

Is there a css trick to make the scroll not jump like that? something like `visibility` act (save the space).

```
 <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
        <div>im left</div>
        <div>im right</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

.foo {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  &:hover {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}

.bar {
  height: 3000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-dream-25yy9?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

[image]

with hover (the text is move aside).

[image]

Comment: Either you have to reserve a space for the scrollbar or you will have to move the scrollbar over the text.

Comment: how I do reserve space for the scrollbar? I try with padding but it's not works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this worked. Adjust the padding of `foo` as below. Adding a padding right for the element `foo` reserves the space for the scrollbar. This padding is removed on hover. This is a tricky one. Make sure this is working on all browsers as different browsers have different type of scrollbars. This is just to give you an idea.

N.B : I have checked this in google chrome, Windows.

```
.foo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding-right: 17px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    &:hover {
      overflow-y: auto;
      padding-right: 0px;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Set `overflow-y` to `scroll` in hover if you need to eliminate the jump when there is no scrollbar.

Comment: ohhh the padding-right solve this. thank you!

Comment: @JonSud Happy to help. Check this in other browsers too. I have a doubt in the padding value in mac systems. There is a chance that the padding value may vary with scrollbar width.

Comment: yes it works, but when I don't have scrolling it's not works as expected... the overflow-y is auto so the content can be without scroll.. what can I do to fix that?

Comment: I didn't get you. Could you please clarify ?

Comment: yes. set the .bar selector to be height of 100px then hover the div and leave, you will see the jump again..

Comment: I change from auto to scroll and works fine. you can add this to the answer please?

Comment: Ok. I see that. We have added the padding right assuming there will be a scroll bar. So either you will have to set `overflow-y` to `scroll` on hover or use javascript to add classes on checking the scrollbar is active or not

Comment: @JonSud Sure. I have added that to the answer

Answer (score 2):

This solution reserves space for the scrollbar using `padding-right` on the inner `div` and then removes the padding on hover.

I'm hesitant to post it as an answer though because it just seems a bit wonky.

```css
.foo {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding-right: 13.5px;
}

.foo:hover {
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.bar {
  height: 3000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
      <div>im left</div>
      <div>im right</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```